# How to complete Call of Cthulhu 'Journey to devil reef' mission?

Tags: pc, call-of-cthulhu-dcote

I have been playing "Call of Cthulhu: Dark Corners of the earth" on my PC. Now I am in a mission where Jack is rescued by the USS Urania, a coast guard cutter, which is part of a group heading to Devil's Reef on February 10, following up on a lead provided by the FBI.

The target of this mission is to surpass tsunamis created by priests.I want to shoot at them, but I cannot see those targets using telescope. When searched in Google, it is found that there is a bug in the game.

How can I overcome this bug?

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods, the first is a bypass.

[DCoTEPatch](https://dcotetools.sucklead.com/p/dcotepatch.html) (some features require the retail game, "blue light bug" doesn't) skips the problematic section, the setting is "Skip the blue light bug! (script will treat sorcerers as killed after 3rd wave)".

[image]

---

Invisible targets is apparently caused by a shader bug on modern operating systems, from [PC Gaming Wiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu:_Dark_Corners_of_the_Earth#Invisible_cannon_targets):

> **Use fixed shaders**
>
> 1. Download [Call_of_Cthulhu_Modern_OS_BUGFIX](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/859-call-of-cthulhu-dark-corners-of-the-earth-modern-os-shader-fix/).
> 2. Copy `Resources` folder to the installation folder.

[original mod release announcement](https://web.archive.org/web/20200427102129/https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/discover/214174/call-of-cthulhu-corrupted-graphics-windows-7-fix-/)

> Without the fix sorcerers are invisible:
>
> [image]
>
> With fix sorcerers and blue lights are visible:
>
> [image]

**UPDATE**:

[The GOG version has since been released](https://www.gog.com/news/release_call_of_cthulhu_dark_corners_of_the_earth) and the build ships with fixes, [from PC Gaming Wiki](https://www.pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu:_Dark_Corners_of_the_Earth#Version_differences) (partially rewritten):

> The GOG.com version includes various small fixes, including: proper Vsync functionality, a fix for the triangle raindrops on AMD cards and a custom-made fix provided by user Guzz which allows the invisible sorcerers on the reef to appear properly, in addition to restoring skybox rendering.

Answer (score 1):

The locations of the targets are always the same, so you can (at least in theory) hit them by setting the guide arrows to certain locations.

According to the quide linked below, these locations are:

Middle target:
horizontal ruler: exactly the middle
vertical ruler: line 8 from bottom

Left target:
horizontal ruler: line 4 from right
vertical ruler: line 11 from bottom

Right target:
horizontal ruler: line 9 from left
vertical ruler: line 11 from bottom

I don't know if there is any sort of hit confirmation, but if you get them all, the game will continue. A few comments in the linked guide suggest making several shots per target.

Source (with screenshots): http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=144143757